# Running a proxi server in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, rack, mongrel

Since rails does not have a mechanism for multi-threading, what is the common good-practice of handling multiple requests at the same time?

Is it usually done by having Apache redirect to something called "Mongrel" or is that different in the Rails3 architecture with the more current solution called something like Rack?

My application does not have to handle thousands of users, but it does have to handle minimal concurrency in an elegant manner.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the job of the rack server. You might look into unicorn or thin as alternatives to mongrel.

Comment: Thanks - does Apache need to be a part of this?  Or is it handled just within rack/unicorn architecture?

Comment: Yes, you want a web server such as Apache or nginx in production. It will serve static assets (images, javascript files, etc.) and reverse-proxy requests to the app server.